# Textbox cursor not visible in webpage

Tags: javascript, focus

I have webpage in which text box present but the problem is input cursor is not visible inside the textbox, but when I start typing cursor is visible I tried something like this but it is not working

```
var textBoxElement =  document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Type a message here"]');
if (textBoxElement){
    document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Type a message here"]').blur();
    document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Type a message here"]').focus();
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more code snippet?

Comment: it is skype [web](https://web.skype.com/) and i am using electron user agent.

Comment: do you use div as an editable?